# Extending a FilteringSelect / AutoComplete with Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, autocomplete, symfony

I have an AutoComplete working with model names in the code below.  I am having difficulty extending it to make the autocomplete include the brand names.

For example, if there is a brand of Sony with models ST1 and ST2, I would like to be able to type Sony and get two rows - Sony ST1 and Sony ST2, but if I type ST1, I would like one row - Sony ST1.

**Controller code**

```
/**
 * @View()
 */
public function getModelsAction( Request $request )
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted( 'ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!' );

    $modelName = str_replace( '*', '%', $request->get( 'name' ) );

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select( 'm' )
            ->from( 'AppBundle:Model', 'm' );

    $queryBuilder->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->like( 'm.name', '?1' )
    );
    $queryBuilder->setParameter( 1, $modelName );

    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
    $modelCollection = $query->getResult();
    $data = [];

    foreach( $modelCollection as $m )
    {
        $item = [
            'id' => $m->getId(),
            'name' => $m->getName(),
        ];

        $data[] = $item;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

**Connection between brands and models** (annotation)

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $brands
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Model", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="brand_model",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="model_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, nullable=false)}
 *      )
 */
protected $models = null;
```

**Database**

**brand**

```
dev=# \d brand
                                  Table "public.brand"
   Column   |              Type              |                 Modifiers                 
------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                        | not null
 name       | character varying(64)          | default NULL::character varying
 active     | boolean                        | not null
 deleted_at | timestamp(0) without time zone | default NULL::timestamp without time zone
 comment    | character varying(64)          | default NULL::character varying
Indexes:
    "brand_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "manufacturer_brand" CONSTRAINT "fk_170c6d4844f5d008" FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brand(id)
    TABLE "brand_model" CONSTRAINT "fk_8c6cbbce44f5d008" FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brand(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**model**

```
dev=# \d model
                                  Table "public.model"
   Column   |              Type              |                 Modifiers                 
------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                        | not null
 name       | character varying(64)          | default NULL::character varying
 comment    | character varying(64)          | default NULL::character varying
 active     | boolean                        | not null
 deleted_at | timestamp(0) without time zone | default NULL::timestamp without time zone
Indexes:
    "model_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "brand_model" CONSTRAINT "fk_8c6cbbce7975b7e7" FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES model(id)
```

**brand_model**

```
dev=# \d brand_model
   Table "public.brand_model"
  Column  |  Type   | Modifiers 
----------+---------+-----------
 brand_id | integer | not null
 model_id | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "brand_model_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (brand_id, model_id)
    "uniq_8c6cbbce7975b7e7" UNIQUE, btree (model_id)
    "idx_8c6cbbce44f5d008" btree (brand_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_8c6cbbce44f5d008" FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brand(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "fk_8c6cbbce7975b7e7" FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES model(id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query builder:

```
$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('m.id, CONCAT(CONCAT(b.name, ' '), m.name)')
    ->from('AppBundle:Model', 'm')
    ->innerJoin('m.brands', 'b')
    ->where("CONCAT(CONCAT(b.name, ' '), m.name)' LIKE :brand_model")
    ->setParameter('brand_model', $brandModel)
;
```

Make sure you have defined the other side of the many-to-many relationship on your `Model` entity:

```
class Model
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Brand", mappedBy="models")
     */
    private $brands;
}
```

And now your controller is smaller thanks to the defined parameters in the `->select(...)` expression (no need for a `foreach`, Doctrine will do it for you):

```
public function getModelsAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    // $queryBuilder = ...

    $data = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $data;
}
```

Note that I changed by the way your PHP coding style to conform to PSR coding standards.